# ¿Cómo establecer un parámetro de tipo Anónimo en una función?

Tags: c#

Según la documentación de Microsoft este es uno de los casos en los que no se puede usar estos tipos de datos, sin embargo he visto que como heredan de object se pueden usar de esta forma, ahora el problema esta en volver a convertir el objeto object en AnonymousType para poder acceder a sus propiedades.

Un ejemplo claro de esto lo tiene SugarSQLite un ORM para SQLite que descargue de Github en el cual presenta varias funciones como esta:

```
  List<T> SqlSugarClient.SqlQuery<T>(string sql, object whereObj = null)
```

La empleo de esta manera

```
  List<Persona> personas = Client.SqlSugarClient.SqlQuery<Persona>("select * from personas where activo=@activo", new { activo = 1});
```

Se cual función dentro de la clase SqlSugarClient el usa para extraer los datos del object pero no quiero usar esta libreria solo para eso.

En fin me gustaria saber como accedo a las propiedades de un objeto de tipo AnonymousType desde el cuerpo de una funcion donde ese objeto ha sido pasado por parametros. Actualmente estoy usando c# 5.0 con netFramework 4.5.2

Comment: Hola Dariel, ¿cuál es tu pregunta?, no veo que hayas formulado alguna

Comment: Si, tal ves el titulo en si no es la pregunta, la verdadera incognita seria como accedo a las propiedades de un objeto de tipo AnonymousType desde el cuerpo de una funcion donde ese objeto ha sido pasado por parametros.

Comment: Agrega tu comentario como parte de la pregunta. es muy buena..

Comment: Hay una hermosa respuesta en SO eng.. debes aclarar que version de C# estas, porque fue cambiando el metodo. si lo aclaras traduzco esa respuesta.

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta con los datos que me pedistes. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para leer las propiedades de un tipo anonimo, se hace igual que con un tipo concreto: haciendo reflection.

```
object tipoAnonimo= new { nombre = "Einer", trabajo = "Programador" };

// obteniendo los nombres de las propiedades del objeto anonimo
List<string> nombrePropiedades = tipoAnonimo.GetType().GetProperties().Select(X=>X.Name).ToList();

// obteniendo los valores de cada propiedad del tipo anonimo
List<String> valores = tipoAnonimo.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(tipoAnonimo).ToString()).ToList();

   // imprimimos los nombres y valores del objeto
    nombrePropiedades.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // "Nombre", "trabajo"
    valores.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); // "Einer", "Programador"
```

Recuerda que al final un objeto anonimo es una clase generada por el compilador donde todas las propiedades solamente tienen getter publico.

Comment: Perfecta tu respuesta me sirvio de mucho aki abajo te dejo como respuesta lo ke keria hacer y gracias a ti lo solucioné.

Answer (score 0):

Imaginense que quiero hacer una aplicación que dado el nombre de una persona y su edad me diga si es mayor de edad. Si tuviera una función que reciviera un parámetro de tipo AnonymousType la solución seria algo como esto

```
    static object DameValor(object obj, string propiedad)
    {
        //Devuelvo el valor la propiedad del objeto "obj" cuyo nombre paso como 2do parametro
       return obj.GetType().GetProperties().Single(x => x.Name.Equals(propiedad)).GetValue(obj);
    }

    //Verifico si la persona representada por el objeto pasado por parámetro es mayor o menor de edad
    static void MayordeEdad(object persona)
    {
        //Nombres de las propiedades que debe tener el parámetro
        string[] props = new string[] { "nombre", "edad" };
        //Verifico que esas propiedades existan en el objeto pasado en la función
        bool coincide = (persona.GetType().GetProperties().Select(X => X.Name).Where(n => props.Contains(n)).Count() == 2);
        //Si todo esta bien
        if (coincide)
        {
            //Obtengo el valor de la propiedad "nombre" (indice 0 del arreglo props)
            string nombre = DameValor(persona, props[0]).ToString();
            //Obtengo el valor de la propiedad "edad" (indice 1 del arreglo props)
            int edad = (int)DameValor(persona, props[1]);
            //Mensaje a mostrar en dependencia de la edad de la persona
            string msg = (edad > 18) ? "eres mayor de edad." : "eres menor de edad.";
            //Muestro el nombre y el mensaje
            Console.WriteLine("Hola " + nombre+", "+msg);
        }
        else
        {
            //Si no coincide con las propiedades muestro un error
            Console.WriteLine("El objeto pasado no contiene los datos necesarios");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //llamo a la funcion para ver si esta persona es mayor o menor de edad
        MayordeEdad(new { nombre = "Dariel", edad = 16 });
    }
```

Comment: Se que ya resolviste tu problema, pero me queda una duda: ¿Porque habría de ser necesario complicarse tanto en hacer un código de esa manera?

Comment: Ese ejemplo que puse no es la pieza angular de mi problema, era un mero ejemplo de su uso, en el comienzo de la formulación de la pregunta hice una explicación de lo que hacía una función de la librería SugarSQLite, y ese es el mas conciso de los ejemplos, si necesitas una funcion que realice una consulta a una base de datos y necesitaces cambiar constantemente los criterios de tu busqueda no podrias hacerlo normalmente como (int parametroA, string parametro b, etc) lo puedes hacer con (params object[] parametros), pero te enredas a la hora de llamarla y pierde en entendimiento.